# App locking possibilities with a rooted device

Tags: android, locking, root, su

I'm looking for a way to lock certain apps from being opened, unless i input the password that's needed.

There are many apps that do this, but none in the way i want.
They all open the application for a split second, and then show their own activity as an overlay, when trying to launch the locked application. Definitely not acceptable.
I also want use fingerprint to unlock, and very few of the current apps support this.

I'm quite sure i'll need root access for this, and this is fine. I've had a rooted device for many years.

I haven't been able to find much on how to intercept intents from the system, or how to block apps from opening with root, so i'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction?

I'm an experienced Android developer, so the general UI/fingerprint will not be a problem, i'm only lacking experience in working with root access and what possible/not possible.